# Can I use opencv functions such as cv::multiply with std::vector<cv::Mat> as input and output arguments?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Reading opencv's docs it seems to me that I could use std::vector as intput and ouput arguments of any function receiving `InputArray` and outputing `OutputArray` classes, e.g `cv::multiply`

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#gsc.tab=0

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga979d898a58d7f61c53003e162e7ad89f

However, I don't seem to be able to get it to work:

```
float data[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, data);

std::vector<cv::Mat> vecMat = {mat, mat, mat};


std::vector<cv::Mat> outputVecMat;
cv::multiply(vecMat, vecMat, outputVecMat);
```

Am I doing something wrong here or just miss interpreting the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputArray` is *basically* a wrapper class around `cv::Mat` and `std::vector<T>`. But `multiply` (the same for divide) expects a 1 or 2 dimensional matrix. For example, a valid code could be:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    float data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, data);

    // Multiply cv::Mat
    cv::Mat outMat;
    cv::multiply(mat, mat, outMat);

    // Multiply std::vector
    std::vector<float> vec(data, data + 9);
    std::vector<float> outVec;
    cv::multiply(vec, vec, outVec);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to multiply the matrices into a `std::vector<cv::Mat>` (which has 3 dimensions), you need do a little extra work, defining your own function (`mymul` here):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>


void mymul(const std::vector<cv::Mat>& src1, const std::vector<cv::Mat>& src2, std::vector<cv::Mat>& dst)
{
    dst.clear();

    // Be sure that src1 and src2 have the same number of elements
    CV_Assert(src1.size() == src2.size());

    dst.resize(src1.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < src1.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::multiply(src1[i], src2[i], dst[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    float data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, data);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> vecMat = { mat, mat, mat };

    std::vector<cv::Mat> outputVecMat;

    // Call custom multiply that works on std::vector<cv::Mat>
    mymul(vecMat, vecMat, outputVecMat);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The issue here **is not** that the `InputArray` is not formed correctly. It is in fact created correctly with `kind` equal to `STD_VECTOR_MAT`. The issue **is** that `multiply` expects the `InputArray` to be either a `cv::Mat` or a `std::vector<T>`, where `T` is a built-in type (`int`, `float`, etc...).

You can see that OpenCV functions that accepts `std::vector<cv::Mat>` has arguments of type `cv::InputArrayOfArrays` or `cv::OutputArrayOfArrays`, where clearly the type `T` of the `std::vector` is of type `cv::Mat`.

Comment: Yes, that's how I had been doing it but then I read this part of the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#gsc.tab=0) where it says that an `InputArray` can be constructed form a `std::vector<Mat>`. Is this not true then?